# Importing a Password from a File to a CLI command Parameter in Linux/Unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, import, passwords

I am finding it quite difficult to do the following:

I have a script that looks like this **./Something host password** and what it does is simply copy files from one host to another, all it needs is for the host name and password, say:
**./Something host1 Password1**

I want to run this as a daily Cronjob, but I don't want to have the password visible in the crontab when running the script or even having to hard code the Password as part of the script instead of adding it as part of a command parameter.

So I have decided to create a file called "Password", that contains the password, I would then want to use this file and import the password inside it to the Password Script variable.

The Cronjob will look like this:

- - - - - /bin/bash /home/yourname/yourscript.sh MyHostName

as you can see I want to replace the password and instead retrieve it from a file, like:

- - - - - /bin/bash /home/yourname/yourscript.sh MyHostName $(PasswordFile.txt)

What would be the best way to implement this?

Note: If the question still doesnt make sense please let me know.

Comment: You're going to have to revise your question. Give some details. Maybe even some code. Right now I have no idea what you're _really_ trying to accomplish.

Comment: I thought that might happen, ill edit my question now - Thanks

Comment: Into cron? Then I delete my answer as it requires interactive password protect... A

Comment: @MeaCulpa The purpose it to remove it from cron, so I import it from a file instead

Comment: @jordanm Yes they can, all they have to do is do a crontab -l and they can see everything and I really dont want to take any risks, So what would be the best way to import a password from a file to the password Variable when running the script?

Comment: I deleted my comment because reading a separate file inside of the script does at least prevent the password from appearing it `ps` output. Other user's can not view your crontab file with crontab -l, only your user and root. I would have left my comment if your response came in prior to me deleting it (so your response would actually make sense).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not that difficult. Say your script is in your home directory, your crontab -l will look like

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/yourname/yourscript.sh
```

And make your script only readable to you:

```
chmod 700 yourscript.sh
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding to my question Raynix, I dont know others have been downgrading my question and removing points.
Thats exactly what I want to do, but the password will still remain visible as th Cronjob will look like this:

* * * * * /bin/bash /home/yourname/yourscript.sh MyHostName <Password>

as you can see I want to replace the password and instead retrieve it from a file, like:

* * * * * /bin/bash /home/yourname/yourscript.sh MyHostName $(PasswordFile.txt)

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What raynix means is that you DO hardcode the password into the script, but make the script only readable to yourself. I'd say that achieves your goal just as well.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I cant do that, they simply wont allow any password to be hard coded and specifically requested it to be retrieved from a separate file, I understand how this solves my problem and I am very thankful for you guys helping me out, but I just need to know how I can read the password from a file when executing the script?

Comment: You mean like this? 

`/bin/bash /path/to/yourscript.sh < password.txt`